# Using OpenSCManager to load the Service Database of a non-running Windows installation

Tags: c, winapi, windows-services, offline

I am pulling (in the IT sense) hard drives from working machines and need to adjust **their service configuration in the registry**. In the Windows API `OpenSCManager`, which is used to edit services in the registry, has a sparsely documented `lpDatabaseName` parameter. Can I use that, say if a Working **but not running** Windows install is mounted as drive `E:\`? (the running Windows install is mounted on drive `C:\`)

Could I do e.g. `OpenSCManager(NULL, "E:\Windows\WHAT_IS_THE_FILENAME", SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)`. Then use the handle to edit the service configuration on drive `E:\`?
What is the file path for the second parameter? i.e. where would I find this service database file on drive `E:\`?

Comment: I seriously doubt it.  From what I understand the SCM functions communicate via LPC to the running instance of SCM; I seriously doubt these can be used to work with an offline installation.  However, it's not rocket science.  You can fiddle directly with the offline system's registry to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that myself, however, what if the edition of Windows was the same? Wouldn't the database be the same as well? What's the purpose of `OpenSCManager()` `lpDatabaseName` parameter? How is it used normally?

Comment: It is probably a backward compatibility remnant.  AFAIK the lpDatabaseName parameter can only ever be NULL or SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE.  There is also a define for SERVICES_FAILED_DATABASE, but trying to open it results in ERROR_DATABASE_DOES_NOT_EXIST.  Passing any other string results in ERROR_INVALID_NAME.  Here is some [documentation on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245942%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx) the protocol which describes that parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [SCM remote protocol specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245942%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx), lpDatabaseName can only be NULL, "ServicesActive", or "ServicesFailed".